# NSJSONSerialization return null

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5

The code listed below return 4 items very good but when i increase the number of items say limit 5 then it return null, can someone told me why its behaving like this?

```
NSString *hostStr = @"http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/product.json.php?";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
NSError *error;
product = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

product.json.php return the following with 4 items

```
{
    "products": {
        "19": [
            {
                "id": "19",
                "name": "Save $240 on your next photo session",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558127351.jpg",
                "highlight": "This is a fantastic offer! You can save 63% with this offer the next time you need an on-site photographer."
            }
        ],
        "21": [
            {
                "id": "21",
                "name": "One Hour Massage",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558127352.jpg",
                "highlight": "With this special offer receive one hour massage for $35. If you have ever wanted a massage after a long day, this is it! Buy one now for yourself or a loved one. You will save almost 70% with this o"
            }
        ],
        "22": [
            {
                "id": "22",
                "name": "Start your spring cleaning with this Offer! Get one area cleaned for Half-Price!",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558127353.jpg",
                "highlight": "For only $40 you can save on having your carpet cleaned with this offer! Save 50% with this offer and receive a free gift."
            }
        ],
        "23": [
            {
                "id": "23",
                "name": "Let Their Creativity Unwined",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558127354.jpg",
                "highlight": "For only $60 children can express themselves with art! With this offer you can see what creativity your child is keeping bottled up with this 2 hour class!"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

this is the result of product.json.php with 5 items

```
{
    "products": {
        "19": [
            {
                "id": "19",
                "name": "Save $240 on your next photo session",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558151441.jpg",
                "highlight": "This is a fantastic offer! You can save 63% with this offer the next time you need an on-site photographer."
           }
        ],
        "21": [
            {
                "id": "21",
                "name": "One Hour Massage",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558151442.jpg",
                "highlight": "With this special offer receive one hour massage for $35. If you have ever wanted a massage after a long day, this is it! Buy one now for yourself or a loved one. You will save almost 70% with this o"
            }
        ],
        "22": [
            {
                "id": "22",
                "name": "Start your spring cleaning with this Offer! Get one area cleaned for Half-Price!",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558151443.jpg",
                "highlight": "For only $40 you can save on having your carpet cleaned with this offer! Save 50% with this offer and receive a free gift."
            }
        ],
        "23": [
            {
                "id": "23",
                "name": "Let Their Creativity Unwined",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558151444.jpg",
                "highlight": "For only $60 children can express themselves with art! With this offer you can see what creativity your child is keeping bottled up with this 2 hour class!"
            }
        ],
        "24": [
            {
                "id": "24",
                "name": "Custom framing for only $49! An offer valued at $200",
                "image_url": "http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/images/13558151445.jpg",
                "highlight": "Framing doesn’t have to be expensive! Now with this offer you can get $200 worth of framing for only $49. Don’t let your art hang without a frame, take advantage of this offer. "
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information. Is there anything interesting in `error`? What exactly does `product.json.php` return and what is the difference in JSON between 4 and 5 objects returned?

Comment: Show us the JSON string that is returned for 5 products? The return value NULL suggests it could not be parsed/serialized, ie it might not be valid JSON.

Comment: I have edited the question and you can see the return of product.json.php,, it returned 4 items very good but when i want to fetch 5 products then it return null

Comment: What does product.json.php produce when fetching 5 products (not serializing it)?

Comment: @John you mean when i log it? if yes it produce this **2012-12-18 11:29:34.779 StraightOffer[5339:c07] products:(null)**

Comment: NSLog the contents of error.

Comment: no error is generated it just return a `null`

Comment: Can you please show the json with 5 objects?

Comment: When i log the error object it also print `null`

Comment: @Aadhira i have edited the question you can see the json for 5 items at the end

Comment: Check your `error` variable and post the error description if it's not `nil`

Comment: Log your error: `NSLog(@"error:%@",error.userInfo);`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella OP already said the error is `nil`. This is going in circles.

Comment: sorry I lost it in the comments...

Comment: `NSLog(@"error:%@",error.userInfo);` also return `null`

Comment: What is `product`? Is it an `ivar`? Are you testing on device or simulator? Will any 5 items cause the problem? Do any items have special characters (not properly encoded) in the data? Are you logging the value of `product` immediately after the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` call, like: `NSLog(@"product:%@",product);` on literally the next line of code? I find all of this exceedingly odd since `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` should either return a valid CoreFoundation object or set the error pointer. At least that's what the comments in the header file seem to indicate.

Comment: the application is for shoppong cart, tap cell from navigation will show the detail view, when i log products it print `nil` in console but when i fetch 4 item it print all 4 items

Comment: I got the issue - when it see some special character say single quote in the content it stop execution,, now please help me how i will fix if i need the special character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `NSJSONSerialization`'s `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method:

> The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the
>   JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE.

Since you seem to have control over the server source code, your URL is "`http://localhost:8888/`", the next bit also applies:

> The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you
>   have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

If you truly need characters not in `UTF-8` try `UTF-16`, or encode the special characters in percent escapes.